# How to modify the autor of an item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

On a SharePoint site I have a workflow that allows users to duplicate an item from a list. I found out when a user duplicate an item the author(field created by) of this item remains the first person who created this item. How I can modify this workflow so that the author of the item becomes the person who duplicated the item?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you can change it via workflow as this is readOnly field, but i know you can set it via using powershell. here is the code for it

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA 0 
#specify new user - login name 
$newuser = "Support\paulmather" 
#specify the web URL 
$site = get-SPWeb http://vm353/pwa/ProjectBICenter 
#specify the list name 
$list = $site.Lists["Test"] 
$listitems = $list.Items 
$user = get-SPuser -Web $site -Identity $newuser 
#loop through each list item and update 
foreach ($listitem in $listitems) 
    { 

        $listitem["Author"] = $user 
        $listitem["Editor"] = $user        
        $listitem.Update() 
        write-host $listitem["Name"] "has been updated. The author and editor has been set to $user" 

    } 
$site.Update() 
$site.Dispose()
```

[Update SharePoint list item Author and Editor](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/projectserver/Update-SharePoint-list-4e6272ab)

Comment: Don't you have to use `.SystemUpdate()` on the list item to override those columns? Or is that just for the Modified Date?